# why does try / catch in javascript fail in IE

Tags: javascript, html5-video, try-catch

```
 Try
 {
myTextTrack = myPlayer.addTextTrack( 'subtitles','myLabel','en' );
  }  catch(err)
 {
alert('This browser does not support the comments on the video.');
return;
  }
```

The above should trigger the alert in IE (not in Chrome).  But it gives a script syntax error.  The code is generated by asp.net and then inserted, so there are carriage return/linefeeds after every line.  But that should not matter.

Comment: Is that what the code looks like, ie. `Try` rather than `try`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're able, change the capital T in Try to t.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is case sensitive. `try` should be lower case

```
 try
 {
myTextTrack = myPlayer.addTextTrack( 'subtitles','myLabel','en' );
  }  catch(err)
 {
alert('This browser does not support the comments on the video.');
return;
  }
```